# Need help stopping slideshow using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run into an issue with jQuery code that I'd like some help on.  While the next and previous buttons work correctly, there appears to be an issue correctly stopping a slideshow.  This is probably something we're completely overlooking, but I can't see *what*.

**There is no JavaScript errors showing in the console.**  The interrupt method was being reached - at one point I had *console.log* calls in there to verify (cleaned up for presentation reasons).

http://jsfiddle.net/eLn83ep0/

Your help is much appreciated.

The below code is the functionality for prev/stop/start/next:

```
      if ($(settings.next).size()) {

        $(settings.next).bind('click.scrollface', function (e) {
          methods.interrupt.call($this);
          methods.next.call($this);
        });

      }

      if ($(settings.pause).size()) {

        $(settings.pause).bind('click.scrollface', function (e) {
            methods.interrupt.call($this);
        });

      }
      if ($(settings.play).size()) {

        $(settings.play).bind('click.scrollface', function (e) {
          methods.interrupt.call($this);
          methods.start.call($this);
        });

      }

      /*
      * Setup up prev bindings
      */

      if ($(settings.prev).size()) {

        $(settings.prev).bind('click.scrollface', function (e) {
          methods.interrupt.call($this);
          methods.prev.call($this);
        });

      }
```

Here is the method for interrupt:

```
interrupt: function (time) {
  return $(this).each(function () {

    var data = $(this).data('scrollface');
    console.log(data);
    console.log('...');
    if (!data) {
      return false;
    }


    var $this = $(this),
    period    = 0;


    /*
    * Stop the timer, and wait a period of time before restarting it.
    * Period defaults to the timer interval
    */

    if (data.timer) {
      if (typeof time !== "number") {
        period = data.interval;
      } else {
        period = time;
      }

      methods.stop.call(this);

      setTimeout(function resume_timer () {
      clearInterval(data.timer);
      data.timer = null;
        methods.start.call($this);
      }, period);

    }

  });

},
```

Comment: are you getting an error? It's not clear from your question what is wrong.

Comment: Hi DLeh, there is no error whatsoever.  It's actually running the interrupt method - this is from the jQuery scrollface library - but failing to stop the actual slideshow.

Comment: @WSTeam I suspect this comment here holds a hint to your issue. In jquery.scrollface.js `/*
        * Stop the timer, and wait a period of time before restarting it.
        * Period defaults to the timer interval
        */` see, you notice it interrupts the sildshow only for a short time. So pause isn't the same as stop. it's literally pause for a moment. Instead call `stop`

Answer (score 0):

```
  if ($(settings.pause).size()) {
        $(settings.pause).bind('click.scrollface', function (e)        
            methods.stop.call($this);               
        });

  }
  if ($(settings.play).size()) {
       $(settings.play).bind('click.scrollface', function (e) {
           methods.start.call($this);             
        });
  }
```

and delete the interrupt call in prev and next

```
   //methods.interrupt.call(this);
```

because the interrupt method stopping the interval method and after timeout starting again, so most time you pause in this timeout but after this timeout  the interrupt method starting the intervall again and dont care if you stoped it manually

see your updated fiddle working here http://jsfiddle.net/7ko4rdda/

**Edit**:

if you call interrupt with 0 for the buttons prev next click handler then you have the expected behavier that the  period for the intervall starts new after next/prev click

```
if ($(settings.prev).size()) {
    $(settings.prev).bind('click.scrollface', function (e) {
          methods.interrupt.call($this,0);
          methods.prev.call($this);
     });

}
if ($(settings.next).size()) {
     $(settings.next).bind('click.scrollface', function (e) {
          methods.interrupt.call($this,0);
          methods.next.call($this);
     });

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ko4rdda/1/